# Streaming data from on-prem database to Oracle OCI Obejctstorage

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

I have an on-prem database that has 50GB of JSON data. I'm planning to take the backup of this data to OCI object storage using Java SDK to a single object in a bucket. on-prem database paginates JSON data result. How can I stream/upload each page of data to OCI object storage whenever it arrives? Do I need to use multipart upload? Is there any example that shows the streaming of data to object storage?

The example in SDK shows uploading a file to Objectstorage but my requirement is to stream data without storing it to temp files.

Comment: Have you checked the Streaming service? It can write the contents of your stream directly to an Object Storage bucket. See this blogpost for more details:
https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/publishing-to-object-storage-from-oracle-streaming-service

Comment: @lsarecz Thanks for the comment. OSS seems overkill for my requirements. I just need to export my database content to Object storage once.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to upload the individual JSON pages, or do you need to combine them back together first into a single JSON object?

I don't think the OCI Java SDK can help you with combining the different pages. For that, you may need a JSON serializer/deserializer, or possibly even work with plain JSON `String`s. If the object is large enough, you may not want to actually parse it. Handling `String`s is less robust, but possibly faster and more memory-efficient.

To upload, you would either use `putObject` in the `ObjectStorageClient`, or use the `UploadManager`. The latter can upload in multiple parts and is ideal for large objects. Here is an example: https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/blob/master/bmc-examples/src/main/java/UploadObjectExample.java